# Unable to setup an iterator to a std::map of std::pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std-pair

I have a map, whose values are std::pair.

The compiler complains as follows when trying to setup an iterator, but I can't understand why :

> src/DBConnector.cpp: In member function ‘int
>   DBConnector::createGenericInsert(std::string,
>   std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
>   std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const
>   std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
>   >, std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::string&)’:
>   src/DBConnector.cpp:354: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in
>   ‘l_oIterEnd = p_mapValues.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::end
>   with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Compare =
>   std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const
>   std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
>   >, std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:251: note: candidates are:
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Compare =
>   std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const
>   std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
>   >, std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >]

My function is as is :

```
int DBConnector::createGenericInsert ( std::string p_sTable , std::map<std::string , std::pair<int,std::string> > p_mapValues , std::string & po_sInsert ) {

    std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> > l_oIter;
    std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> > l_oIterEnd;

    std::string s_Fieldnames;

    l_oIterEnd = p_mapValues.end(); // This is line 354
    l_oIter = p_mapValues.begin();

    s_Fieldnames += l_oIter.first();

    ...
}
```

What is the problem here ? Can a map contain std::pairs ? (Besides, can a map contain keys holding different types ?)

Comment: You declare `l_oIter` as a `std::map`, not an iterator...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't name the type `iterator` correctly!

Please, *please*, save yourself trouble and use `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string>> map_type;

int DBConnector::createGenericInsert (std::string p_sTable, map_type p_mapValues,
                                      std::string & po_sInsert)
{
    std::string s_Fieldnames;

    map_type::iterator l_oIterEnd = p_mapValues.end();
    map_type::iterator l_oIter = p_mapValues.begin();

    s_Fieldnames += l_oIter->first; // !!

    // ...
}
```

Please note that the *value type* of `map<A, B>` is actually `pair<A, B>`, while `B` itself is referred to as the "mapped type". This is important because many operations work on the *value* type, and thus you need to access the `second` part of it to get at the mapped value.

Comment: OP: you will also need to dereference the iterator, e.g. `l_oIter->first()`

Comment: Or, if you have C++11 features available, use `auto`. `auto l_oIterEnd = p_mapValues.end();`

Comment: I feel sooo dumb, didn't notice the ::iterator was missing. Accepted ! +1 for advising typedefs ;)

Answer (score 4):

these are not iterators.

```
std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> > l_oIter;
 std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> > l_oIterEnd;
```

above code should be changed to :

```
   std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> >::iterator l_oIter;
     std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::string> >::iterator l_oIterEnd;
```